# Removing duplications in jsonarray java

Tags: java

I have a json list as follows:

```
"edgelist":[{"value":15.0,"date":20130729,"type":"url","destination":"224883242"},
               {"value":15.0,"date":20130729,"type":"url","destination":"224883243"},
               {"value":15.0,"date":20130730,"type":"url","destination":"224883242"}
             ]
```

Take a look at "destination and date..

Destination 224883242 is repeated twice..

What I want to keep is just latest unique jsons ...
So the output would be

```
"edgelist":[               {"value":15.0,"date":20130729,"type":"url","destination":"224883243"},
                   {"value":15.0,"date":20130730,"type":"url","destination":"224883242"}
                 ]
```

What is the best way to do this...?

If destination and date are same.. keep either but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Model these JSON objects as proper Java objects. Give them a `Class`.
2. Implement `hashcode` and `equals` for that `Class` so that they depend on the `destination` and `date` fields.
3. Push all your objects into a `Set`. The resulting collection will have no duplicates.